# SQL Server backup jobs run twice, but appears to be scheduled once

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2008

I have a scheduled backup that should run once per day, but runs twice. I've scheduled the job to run at 6:30 AM, daily.

If I view the log of that maintenance plan, I can see that it ran today at 5:00 and at 6:20.

If I view the Job History log, it shows that the backup was run once, at 6:20 only.

This job was scheduled to run at 5:00, but was rescheduled to 6:20. I deleted the 5:00 schedule and replaced it with the 6:20 one under the maintenance plan. I've confirmed that only one job is added for this under SQL Server Agent visually under SSMS as well as querying the sysjobs table and the sysjobsteps table.

I'm not sure what the next step might be to track this down is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things I would suggest:

1. Look at the schedule for the maintenance plan and verify the time and recurrence for the maintenance plan.
2. Look at the steps in the maintenence plan to make sure there aren't two backup steps.
3. Delete the maintenance plan and create a new one.

Comment: Those are all good steps, and they are ones that I tried but ended up not being the solution. It ended up being a clone of the VM that was made that never had the backup scripts terminated, so the second machine was running them via its SQL Server Agent.

Comment: This is exactly whats happening to my server.. Question is how do you stop the clone maintenance plans running on the original server?

Comment: Davey, I just manually disable them from SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio). For me, these were under Management/Maintenance Plans. Your other jobs may be under SQK Server Agent/Jobs.